# 301 redirect with load balancer azure c#

Tags: c#, azure, redirect

I am trying to do 301 redirect with following code:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
    var contentId = GetIdFromUrl(url);

    var forwardedHost = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"];
    var proxiedBrand = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["HOST"].ToLower();
    var isRedirectionTrue = IsRedirectionArticleInCollection(contentId);
    var isForwardedHostTrue = forwardedHost.Contains("old.com");
    var urlRedir = url.Replace("v3", "www").Replace("old.com", "new.com");

    Logger.Warn("urlredir: " + urlRedir + ", ContentId: " + contentId + ", Url:" + url + ", isRedirectionTrue: " + isRedirectionTrue + ", ForwardedHost:" + forwardedHost + ", Host: " + proxiedBrand + ", IsForwardedHostTrue: " + isForwardedHostTrue);
    if (contentId > 0 && isRedirectionTrue && isForwardedHostTrue)
    {
        var urlToRedirectTo = "https://dev.www.new.com/";// url.Replace("v3", "www").Replace("old.com", "new.com");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 301;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", urlToRedirectTo);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(urlToRedirectTo, false);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Problem is that redirect is not working. I never get redirected to new domain, whatever i do. If I use hardcoded example dev.www.new.com it goes to dev.www.old.com domain, same thing happens with full url.

Is my redirect correct?

Answer (score 0):

> If I use hardcoded example dev.www.new.com it goes to dev.www.old.com domain, same thing happens with full url.

With your code in if judge sentences, it could **correctly to go** to dev.www.new.com with full url. 
Check the logger and set another log in if judge sentence to ensure you have run into if sentences.

Certainly, you could also use **url rewrite** to redirect based on the **logic expressed in the rewrite rules**. For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

If you still have any problem, please show me detailed your current domain and the redirected domain you want.